# Redirect django url with javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates, django-staticfiles

i have countdown timer with javascript, I want to redirect to another page after countdown is over.countdown works pefectly but it's not redirecting to the result page

i tried this:

app.js

```
var count = 15

var counter = setInterval(timer , 1000)

function timer(){
   count = count-1
   if (count <= 0)
   {
       clearInterval(counter);
       return window.location.replace("{% url'app:result' %}")
   }
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= count + " secs";

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 window.location.href = "{% url'app:result' %}"
```

Answer (score 1):

django template tags work inside the django templates. Since you have above javascript in the `app.js` file, this `{% url'app:result' %}` tag in the line below won't work because it is not valid javascript.

```
return window.location.replace("{% url'app:result' %}")
```

You can try moving the code from app.js into the corresponding django template and see if that works

Comment: Be aware that by using `replace` replaces the history's list last entry. This means that afterward, the back button will not go back to the original page. Assigning the URL to `href` creates a new entry in the history list